# Literature reference: example of stable and unstable manifolds in Henon-Heiles system

Tags: resource-recommendations, stability, non-linear-systems, chaos-theory, complex-systems

There is a quite classical description of chaotic systems based on the behaviour of stable and unstable manifolds around a stationary point of the Poincaré section. It is presented, for example, [here, in slide 9][1], where a sketch of the stable and unstable manifolds on the Poincaré section are drawn by hand.

Now I am looking for a numerical study that reports the graphs of the stable and unstable manifolds, quantitatively evaluated (not just made by hand). Possibly, it should be done for [Hénon-Heiles equations](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Henon-HeilesEquation.html), or, alternatively, for another chaotic Hamiltonian system.  It is important that it reports the conditions, i.e. the coordinates of the fixed point, so that I
can exactly reproduce the calculation.

EDIT: I emphasize that I am looking for an example with the Henon-Heiles system. At least, with a Hamiltonian system. I see various examples with discrete maps, but there it is much easier to find a fixed point.

EDIT 2. I could calculate the fixed point and the stable and unstable manifold but finding such a picture in an already published paper would help. Here is the reason. I am calculating some parameters in various points of the phase space. I represent them on the Poincarè section. I would like to qualitatively show how they behave near fixed points and stable and unstable manifolds. The topic of my paper would not be this comparison, nor the calculation of stable and unstable manifolds, thus I would like to refer the reader to a paper, without having to document the procedure of the calculation.

[1]: [http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~locatell/school1-astronet2/material/lezione_Loca1.pdf](http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/%7Elocatell/school1-astronet2/material/lezione_Loca1.pdf) "KAM Theory and Applications in CelestialMechanics – First Lecture: Chaotic Motions in Hamiltonian Systems", Ugo Locatelli, University of Roma “Tor Vergata”, lecture, 14-th of January, 2013.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 1):

In the chaotic case these manifolds cross infinitely many times and actually foliate the whole accessible space.

A numerical approximation of a finite segment of the manifolds is probably what you're looking for, and that is already given in the presentation you link (page 14):

[image: stable and unstable manifolds for the standard map slide]

If you use one of the usual methods for producing these pictures, even guessed initial coordinates should allow you to reproduce these plots.

Comment: Well, this is not for the Henon-Heiles system. It is not even a Hamiltonian system. It is a discrete mapping that preserves the area, so it is similar to a Poincarè section of a Hamiltonian system, but it is not really. For discrete maps, it is much easier to find fixed points, just by symbolic calculation.

Comment: @DorianoBrogioli This indeed isn't the Hénon-Heiles system — which seemed fine before the question edits. Please also notice this mapping _is_ a Hamiltonian system just as much as the Hénon-Heiles Poincaré map referred in the question — after all the Standard Map also is the Poincaré map of a continuous system, namely the kicked rotor.

Answer (score 1):

What about this [paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.64.066208) ([e-print](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Miguel-Sanjuan/publication/11620674_Wada_basins_and_chaotic_invariant_sets_in_the_Henon-Heiles_system/links/0912f50af5802796c1000000/Wada-basins-and-chaotic-invariant-sets-in-the-Henon-Heiles-system.pdf)):
*Wada basins and chaotic invariant sets in the Hénon-Heiles system*, J Aguirre, J C Vallejo, M A F Sanjuán, Phys. Rev. E **64**, 066208 (2001)

[image]

Comment: The typical image of the Henon-Heiles chaotic domains is a y dot vs. y Poincarè cut, while here the stable and unstable manifolds are shown in y vs. x plane. I am wondering if there is any reason preventing to use the y dot vs y section (I do not find any!).

Comment: @DorianoBrogioli Good question. Without having studied the paper to say for sure, I think it's due to their being interested in scattering...

Comment: Yes, it seems that they study a condition in which the trajectory can escape. Do you have an example in which the trajectories are confined?

Comment: @DorianoBrogioli As far I understand escape is a feature of the original system. As stated in page 77 of the [original paper](https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/full/seri/AJ.../0069//0000073.000.html): "$E=\frac{1}{6}$ is the _energy of escape_ in the potential [...] the star can eventually escape to infinity, if the orbit is ergodic."

Comment: I see that the paper focuses on that regime, but, in Henon-Heiles system, with small enough energy, the trajectories are confined. I find it surprising that, although the Henon-Heiles system is well known, although it is often used as an example of the Poincarè section, in confined conditions, no study of the stable and unstable manifolds is available!

Comment: @DorianoBrogioli I find it surprising too. Unfortunately I can't spare the time right now to search more the literature to confirm it. Since it's so standard and old, I'd start with books and dissertations.

Comment: I already search for it myself, the reason for asking here is to seek for people who already know the answer. I could search further, or, even better, make the calculation myself. The funny thing is that, if I make it myself, I would not be able to publish the results, since it looks a well-known stuff.

Comment: @DorianoBrogioli I don't doubt there's been due diligence. But the field of nonlinear dynamics is not as active any more and such questions often don't receive a lot of attention here, so usually I'm happy to search a bit myself when I don't already have a good reference - in other words, I was just lamenting this time I can't do it. But back to this paper: if you were able to reproduce their picture, this would be enough to trust your simulation, also when looking at the variables you're interested in, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, it would! But I still prefer to find a paper. I edited the question to add why. Thank you again.